# datatable function not found when accessing same view but with route object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, datatables

I have a controller action that lets me access ManageMock.cshtml by either clicking on a navbar menu option that's directly inside _layout.cshtml (the route is `/Mock/ManageMock` ), or on a button that's in the @Renderbody() of _layout.cshtml (route is eg `/Mock/ManageMock/2`)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ManageMock(int? id)
        {
            List<SiteViewModel> sites = await _siteService.List();
            if (id != null)
            {
                ViewBag.LoadSite = id;
            }
            return View(sites);
        }
```

when I go to `/Mock/ManageMock`, datatable runs fine. I don't get any errors

when I go to `/Mock/ManageMock/2`, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function
```

Why is that?

I have this in my `_Layout.cshtml` , right before closing tags of body

```
<environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.18/b-1.5.6/datatables.min.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">        
        </script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o">
        </script>
    </environment>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

Comment: Check if the page in  '/Mock/ManageMock/2' where you have the table has <thead> in it. if not then add it.

Comment: What's inside your ManageMock view? Is there any logic around `ViewBag.LoadSite`?

Comment: <div id="MockListTableContainer" style="padding-top:5%" data-value="@ViewBag.LoadSite"></div>

Comment: when I replace new {id = item.id} fvrom the actionlink with null, everything works fine. This id parameter seems to break everything.  @Html.ActionLink("Mock List", "ManageMock", "Mock", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary btn-sm" })

Comment: it now works when I use a query parameter instead of /{id} . I still dont get why {id} creates a problem